# How to get UserRoles for users other then logged in

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, roles, asp.net-identity

in the Index Action of the Account Controller, I want to be able to allow users to view users of equal or lesser status, but I'm not getting the results I want. One way only returns the Logged in User, the other does not return anything. A user can only have one Role. So far I have this,

```
var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
IList<string> roles;

foreach (var item in pUsers)
{
   userDetails = new listUsersViewModel();
   userDetails.id = item.id;
   userDetails.userName = cEncrypt.decryptUserName(item.userName.Substring(2));

   //***this only returns the role of Logged in User
   roles = um.GetRoles(item.id);

   //***this doesn't return any results
   string[] role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(item.userName);

   //make sure the logged in user has appropriate permissions to view list of users.
   if ((User.IsInRole("Admin") && ((roles[0] == "Admin") || (roles[0] == "Staff") || (roles[0] == "User")))
      || (User.IsInRole("Staff") && ((roles[0] == "Staff") || (roles[0] == "User")))
      || (User.IsInRole("User") && User.Identity.GetUserId() == userDetails.id)
      )
      { userList.Add(userDetails); }
}
```

My web.config in the root of the project looks like this...

```
<system.web>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="myDatabaseName" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a thought. You can do one thing, get all the users from asp.net membership and all the roles from asp.net roles provider and filter out the users based on roles you need. Not very sure if this will work for you though.

Comment: unfortunately the users belong to separate companies and I filter by company before trying to get the roles.  Unless, there's a way that makes it easier than I'm thinking it would be...?